# Java - acces object methods trough an array index

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods

I have a problem with accessing methods from an object inside an array. I'm trying to create a card game. The moment I have created an card object I push them inside an Arraylist. Now when i got for example 5 card objects in this array, i want to access the methods of the card that is [0] index, but I don't know how. Here is the code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Main main = new Main();
      //creates new card
      Card FireElemental = new Card("Fire Elemental");

      // adds card to array
      main.player2FieldCards.add(FireElemental);

      // Now to access it's methods, the example below is not working but 
      // to give an example of what I want.
      main.player2FieldCards.get(0).SomeMethod();
}
```

Comment: That should work. Can you share us the code of `Card` and `Main`?

Comment: very likely, you declared `player2FieldCards` as `ArrayList` without generic type. Something like `ArrayList player2FieldCards = new ArrayList()`, if it is true, you should change it into: `List<Card> player2FieldCards = new ArrayList<>()`

Comment: you should Cast it  ((yourClass)main.player2FieldCards.get(0)).SomeMethod();

Comment: You have a method called `main()`, a class called `Main` and an instance of that class called `main`.  That is confusing; don't do it -- it will create problems later.  Rename the class to something like `CardDeck` and the instance to `playerHand`.  Just make sure that the different things have different names so they are easily and instantly recognisable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean, that in your case "Main" contain arraylist, maybe you forgot to make it generic. You need to add `ArrayList<Card>` instead of pure `ArrayList`, because without generics, you store object element and in order to call method on Card object you need to cast it to Card before.

```
((Card)main.player2FieldCards.get(0)).SomeMethod();
```

Comment: Yes! This was it! Thanks for the help and fast reply!!

Answer (score -1):

I think you are going wrong with the logic section. There are many things that might (or not) be wrong with your solution. Possibly the `List` in your `Main` class definition may not be generic. Things you are trying to do should be something like. The main class should be like.

```
public class Main {
    List<Card> player2FieldCards; //Must not be List player2FieldCards;

    public Main() {
        player2FieldCards = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //Rest of you main method code goes here
    }
}
```

There should be another class named as `Card`. Which must look something like.

```
class Card {
    // Fields declarations 

    // Methods declarations 

    public void SomeMethod() {

    }
}
```

If you have somewhat similar definition of your classes. Then things should work as expected. If not please point it out and ping me back.